# Check whether XML tag exist in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML javax.xml, but i want to know whether a tag exist on a child node For example

```
<tag>
 <child>
  <special_tag>Special</special_tag>
  <normal_tag>Normal</normal_tag>
 </child>
 <child>
  <normal_tag>Normal</normal_tag>
 </child>
</tag>
```

I am trying to know which Child has Special tag and which doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xPath:

```
//child[special_tag]
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the DOM for your xml and use XPath to query for the existence of "special_tag" using //special_tag

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a classic usecase for SAX.
You should register your listener and check the tag name. When it equals to special_tag get the element's parent.

Comment: Why do you think that this is a classic use-case for SAX?